# Databricks command not found in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to copy a file to Azure Databricks DBFS through Azure Devops pipeline. The following is a snippet from the yml file I am using:

```
stages:
- stage: MYBuild
  displayName: "My Build"
  jobs:
    - job: BuildwhlAndRunPytest
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7'
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'

      - script: |
          pip install pytest requests setuptools wheel pytest-cov
          pip install -U databricks-connect==7.3.*
        displayName: 'Load Python Dependencies'

      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true
        clean: true

      - script: |
          echo "y
          $(databricks-host)
          $(databricks-token)
          $(databricks-cluster)
          $(databricks-org-id)
          8787" | databricks-connect configure
          databricks-connect test
        env:
          databricks-token: $(databricks-token)
        displayName: 'Configure DBConnect'

      - script: |
          databricks fs cp test-proj/pyspark-lib/configs/config.ini dbfs:/configs/test-proj/config.ini
```

I get the following error at the stage where I am invoking the databricks fs cp command:

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/2278f7d5-1d96-4c4e-a501-77c07419773b.sh: line 7: databricks: command not found
```

However, when I run `databricks-connect test`, it is able to execute the command successfully. Kindly help if I am missing some steps somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `databricks` command is located in the `databricks-cli` package, not in the `databricks-connect`, so you need to change your `pip install` command.

Also, for `databricks` command you can just set the environment variables `DATABRICKS_HOST` and `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` and it will work, like this:

```yaml
- script: |
    pip install pytest requests setuptools wheel
    pip install -U databricks-cli
  displayName: 'Load Python Dependencies'

- script: |
    databricks fs cp ... dbfs:/...
  env:
    DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
    DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
  displayName: 'Copy artifacts'
```

P.S. Here is an [example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo) on how to do CI/CD on Databricks + notebooks. You could be also interested in [cicd-templates project](https://github.com/databrickslabs/cicd-templates).