# Unable to import init shell file into databrick worksapce using databrick cli

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am tying to import the init shell script file(.sh) into databrick workspace using databrick cli using below command but getting error

command :

```
databricks workspace import --format AUTO test.sh /project/test.sh
Error: Invalid value for '--format' / '-f': Format must be one of: SOURCE, HTML, JUPYTER, DBC
```

if i give SOURCE it is asking to use

```
--language supported (Enum: "SCALA" "PYTHON" "SQL" "R")
```

Can you please help how can i import .sh file into worksapce using CLI

Answer (score 1):

Tested the command with Databricks CLI `v0.209.1` and had no problems importing a shell script file to the Databricks workspace.

The correct usage for this command is:

```
databricks workspace import TARGET_PATH [flags]
```

In your case, as it seems you are trying to import a local file, the correct command should be:

```
databricks workspace import /project/test.sh --file test.sh --format AUTO
```

To check you databricks CLI version type `databricks -v` in the terminal. To upgrade you CLI version follow this guide: https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/migrate.html

Databricks CLI provides pretty good information about its command with `--help`  .e.g. `databricks workspace import --help`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, it seems i have installed old version using PIP install databrick-cli in azure DevOps CICD  , after i have installed new version using curl, I am unable to do automatic Databrick configure.  how can i automate databricks configure without asking for host and token inputs ..i have tried like below but not working with new CLI which work for old cli databricks configure --token<<EOF $(databricksHost) $(databricksToken) EOF which is works for old version Databrick-cli

Comment: If you set those as environment variables: `DATABRICKS_HOST` and `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` the Databricks CLI will use those as configuration.

See this answer for Azure DevOps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67481419/21805629

Comment: Thank you , which helps me to configure Databricks-configure